# Filter the output in the brackets as a list

Tags: groovy, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a lines like :

```
   [Something-26543] One ticket
   [Something-23121] Second ticket
   [Something-21243] Third ticket and so on
```

Can someone advice if there is a a way to grep only the line between the square brackets.
Before:

```
[Something-26543] Another Ticket
```

After filtering:

```
Something-26543
Something-23121
Something-21243
```

What I wrote as an example. Note "asdfasdf" is not between any brackets, so it should not be matched:

```
 def changeString = ['[DPDHLPA-26607] Updating robots.txt', '[DPDHLPA-2321] [DPDHLPA-2322] Updating something.txt', 'asdfasdf']


 def TICKET_LIST = (changeString =~ /(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\]/[0].readLines().unique().sort().join('\n')
        print TICKET_LIST //to see if it got the filtered list
```

But then TICKET LIST shows only the first filter. I need to collect all outputs, because later I will do for loop on "TICKET_LIST" and assemble an URL. I've tried also with collectMany, but that didn't really work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
def ticketList = changeString.findResults { str -> 
    (str =~ /\[([^]]+)].*/).with { 
        it.matches() ? it[0][1] : null
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I have this as a list?

Comment: That is a list.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the noobish question. Can I add trim() and  tokenize("\n") to this. And currently output when printing it shows it in one line : "[DPDHLPA-2321, DPDHLPA-26607]". Not in a list

Comment: In groovy, when you print a list it is serialized to a string on one line with surrounding brackets and comma separated. Like Tim Yates mentioned, that is a List. `println([1,2,3])` -> `[1, 2, 3]` and `println([1,2,3].getClass())` -> `class java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: If you want to trim: `def ticketList = changeStr.findResults { str -> ... }.collect { it.trim() }`

Comment: Or you can trim inline by changing `it[0][1]` to `it[0][1].trim()`